# Parsing lines of text from external file in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, parsing

I am trying to parse a raw email. The desired result is a hash of the lines that contain specific headers.

This is the Ruby file:

```
raw_email = File.open("sample-email.txt", "r")
parsed_email = Hash.new('')

raw_email.each do |line|
  puts line
  header = line.chomp(":")
  puts header
  if header == "Delivered-To"
    parsed_email[:to] = line
  elsif header == "From"
    parsed_email[:from] = line
  elsif header == "Date"
    parsed_email[:date] = line
  elsif header == "Subject"
    parsed_email[:subject] = line
  end
end

puts parsed_email
```

And this is the raw email:

```
Delivered-To: user1@example.com
From: John Doe <user2@example.com>
Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 13:30:14 -0500
Subject: Testing the parser
To: user1@example.com
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
boundary="123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrs"

--123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrs
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer nec 
odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla 
quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum.

--123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrs
Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"

<div dir="ltr">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing 
elit. Integer nec odio. Praesent libero. Sed cursus ante dapibus diam. 
Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis 
ipsum.<br clear="all">
</div>

--089e082c24dc944a9f056028d791--
```

The puts statements are just for my own testing to see if data is being passed along.

What I am getting is each full line put twice and an empty hash put at the end.

I have also tried changing different bits to strings or arrays and I've also tried using `line.split(":", 1)` instead of `line.chomp(":")`

Can someone please explain why this isn't working?

Comment: Chomp removes _trailing_ characters (default is the newline). You want both: `line.chomp.split(":")`

Comment: I see. I was under the impression chomp would "split" at the last found supplied (or default) delimiter in a string and then drop everything after (including the delimiter).

Comment: BTW, your current approach is completely broken for folded header bodies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
raw_email = File.open("sample-email.txt", "r")
parsed_email = {}

raw_email.each do |line|
  case line.split(":")[0]
  when "Delivered-To"
    parsed_email[:to] = line
  when "From"
    parsed_email[:from] = line
  when "Date"
    parsed_email[:date] = line
  when "Subject"
    parsed_email[:subject] = line
  end
end

puts parsed_email
=> {:to=>"Delivered-To: user1@example.com\n", :from=>"From: John Doe <user2@example.com>\n", :date=>"Date: Tue, 12 Dec 2017 13:30:14 -0500\n", :subject=>"Subject: Testing the parser\n"}
```

**Explanation**
You need to split line on `:` and select first. Like this `line.split(":")[0]`

Comment: Of course. I tried it exactly like that originally, but forgot that split returns an array so I had left off the `[0]`. That led me down a rabbit hole of confusion. Thank you so much. This is exactly what I was trying to do.

Comment: This being said, I recommend using a mail parsing gem and not doing it yourself.

Comment: LOL. I completely agree. Normally I would, but, I'm trying to learn how mail parsing works. ;)

Comment: Also: the scan should stop after the first blank line (which marks the end of the headerblock). This avoids scanning the full body (including any attachments), which can be large -- or the body could even contain matching fields which would produce wrong results.